# Subselect com inner join no Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

Na versão Oracle 11g, quando tentamos fazer uma select com uma subselect que liga a tabela interna com a externa por inner join, ocorre o erro "**ORA-00904: "CAMPO": identificador inválido**".

`select count(*) from user_tables A where exists (select 0 from user_indexes B inner join user_ind_columns C on (B.table_name = A.table_name));`

Eu sei que a partir da versão 12c esse erro não ocorre mais, pois tenho acesso a instalações nas duas versões.

Existe algum patch de correção para esse erro na versão 11g, ou ele é corrigido apenas atualizando para a 12c?

Comment: Não tem sentido você colocar na condição de junção de seu subselect uma referência à tabela externa. A condição de junção deve se referir às tabelas B e C. Talvez a referência à tabela A  devesse estar numa cláusula WHERE?

Comment: Sinceramente, não sei se em alguma situação tem sentido fazer dessa forma, esse comando que postei é apenas um exemplo para ilustrar o erro. O fato é que na 12c esse comando executa, e não sei se em alguma versão do SQL Server depois da implementação do inner join ocorria um erro como esse.
Mas a minha dúvida não tem a ver com a sintaxe do comando, e sim se a Oracle lançou uma atualização para o 11g que corrige isso, ou se é somente a partir da 12c que está corrigido mesmo.